# Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming and IE

Tags: adobe, video-streaming, h.264

I'm testing Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming. All is working perfectly, except streaming to IE. Other browsers playback perfectly (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, SeaMonkey, etc). IE however drops frames at the start of every fragment. How can this be fixed?

My test URL is http://vod.heanet.ie/

Comment: The problem seems to have gone in FMS 4.5